# How do I access a field value in the $row variable in a field view theme template?

Tags: 7, views

I'm overriding a field template for one of my views and I want to be able to access another field value from the $row variable. The documentation on the template file shows this:

> When fetching output from the $row, this construct should be used:
>   $data = $row->{$field->field_alias}

My field is called field_calendar_title, but the following doesn't work as expected:

```
$row->{$field->field_calendar_title}
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property...

Is the field "alias" different from the name of the field in the content type?

"Cleansed" output from var_dump of $row:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [node_title] => ...
    [nid] => 568
    [field_data_field_performance_date_delta] => 0
    [field_data_field_performance_date_language] => und
    [field_data_field_performance_date_bundle] => event
    [field_data_field_performance_date_field_performance_date_val] => 2012-03-02 19:00:00
    [field_data_field_performance_date_node_entity_type] => node
    [_field_data] => Array
        (
            [nid] => Array
                (
                    [entity_type] => node
                    [entity] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [vid] => 878
                            [uid] => 0
                            [title] => ...
                            [log] => 
                            [status] => 1
                            [comment] => 0
                            [promote] => 0
                            [sticky] => 0
                            [nid] => 568
                            [type] => event
                            [language] => und
                            [created] => 1329332968
                            [changed] => 1331836509
                            [tnid] => 0
                            [translate] => 0
                            [revision_timestamp] => 1331836509
                            [revision_uid] => 1
                            [body] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [value] => ...
                                                    [summary] => ...
                                                    [safe_summary] => ...
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                                [field_resident_company] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tid] => 3 ) ) )
                                [field_series] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tid] => 36 ) ) )
                                [field_venue] => Array ( )
                                [field_rotator_image] => Array ( )
                                [field_exclude] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 0 ) ) )
                                [field_performance_image] => Array ( )
                                [field_premiere] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 1330714800 [timezone] => UTC [timezone_db] => UTC [date_type] => datestamp ) ) )
                                [field_closing] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 1330714800 [timezone] => UTC [timezone_db] => UTC [date_type] => datestamp ) ) )
                                [field_exclude_update] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 0 ) ) )
                                [field_performance_date] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 2012-03-02 19:00:00 [timezone] => UTC [timezone_db] => UTC [date_type] => datetime ) ) )
                                [field_performance_id] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 1436 [format] => [safe_value] => 1436 ) ) ) [field_event_status] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => open ) ) )
                                [field_calendar_title] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => PSYCHIC EXP [format] => [safe_value] => PSYCHIC EXP ) ) )
                                ...
                        )
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the looks of the `var_dump` you should be able to find your field value with this:

```
$row->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_calendar_title['und'][0]['value'];
```

I really hope there's a better way than that though!

Comment: Sorry I corrected the syntax in my question and it still didn't work. Tried this too and no luck $row->field_calendar_title;

Comment: Hmmm...I think from the error message `$field` is undefined...have you tried doing a `var_dump($row)` to see what's actually in there? You'll probably spot the field you're after pretty easily :)

Comment: Hey Clive, yup I did a var_dump and the field exists under _field_data along with the rest of the field values...

Comment: If you can pop the output of `var_dump($row)` into your question as an edit I might be able to spot the value you need

Comment: @SomethingOn I've updated the answer, it's not pretty but it should work :)

Answer (score 7):

A simpler approach:

```
$rendered_field = $view->render_field($fieldname, $view->row_index);
```

Here, $fieldname is the original (not the view-aliased) fieldname, e.g. 'field_myfield'.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late, but for future reference here's my answer:

The description is pretty vague, but you should literally use:

`$row->{$field->field_alias}`

In your template file it is also noted that:

Variables available:

- $view: The view object
- $field: The field handler object that can process the input
- $row: The raw SQL result that can be used
- $output: The processed output that will normally be used.

In $field there's a field called field_alias. So `$row->{$field->field_alias}` is actually pointing to, in your case, field_calendar_title.

Try making a var_dump of $field and you'll see for yourself.

Hope this helps anyone coming across this post.

Gerben

Comment: It's never too late, still trending question. 1. I don't want to use monstrous @Clive's example, though it works 2. I do want to understand how to work with given variables: $row, $filed, etc. Your suggestion returns only a number (maybe nid or smth), but how can I access precisely my field. What if I have two different fields that I want to get?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is : $fields["field_name"]->content; Where field_name -> cck field name.

Hope that will help !!

Cheers ! Raj

Comment: there is no `$fields` variable available in field template