# How to use field variables in un-formatted view template?

Tags: 7, views, entities, theming

If found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/how-do-i-access-a-field-value-in-the-row-variable-in-a-field-view-theme-templat), but I can't manage to apply it to my case. Here goes. (I'm new to PHP coding and Drupal.)

I want to add a HTML link into each row of my unformatted views template. For each row I want the link for the relevant piece of content.

I used the devel dpm to reveal the variables in the unformatted.tpl.php. But I can't find a variable for the link field. (I've added the Content: Link field in views and it's hidden.)

My understanding at the moment is I'll need to set the variable in the relevant preprocess function, which might look like this:

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {
    $link = Location of link field variable
}
```

And then use it in the views template:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
    <?php print $link; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But I can't find the link information and I can't find similar examples so I've probably gone badly wrong. How would I do that and is my basic understanding ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've managed to get it working with:

```
<?php print $view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$id]['[view_node]']; ?>
```

I tried to use:

```
<?php print $view->style_plugin->row_tokens[$rows['id']]['[view_node]']; ?>
```

But it kept throwing undefined index errors, even though it was valid path from DPM.

rows (array)
  id (value)

id (the variable I used in the top working solution) didn't show in my DPM. Is that because I was calling it for the views unformatted tpl and id is a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer didn't worked for me, as the `row_tokens` array was empty for some reason. Though I managed to access the field using the following:

```
$view->style_plugin->row_plugin->nodes[$view->result[$id]->nid]->my_field_name
```

Here `$id` is the row index, and can be used to get the nid using the `$view->result` array.